# How do you find the derivative of $|x-5|$?

Tags: calculus

I can see that intuitvely that for $x>5$, the slope is $-1$ and for $x<5$, the slope should be $1$. But, is there any way to find the derivative of the function $f(x) = |x-5|$ such that $f'(x)$ looks like a function?

Comment: I think you have the signs of the derivative backward.  That is, the function $f(x)$ is increasing for $x\gt 5$, and decreasing below that.   Of course there is no derivative defined for $f$ at $x=5$.  $f'(x)$ looks like a function to me, albeit one that has a jump discontinuity at $x=5$.

Comment: What do you mean, "such that $f'(x)$ looks like a function"? The derivatives you have obtained for each part of the function simply constitute another piecewise function. There is nothing wrong with this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\frac{d}{du}|u|=u'\frac{|u|}{u}$ this comes from the fact that the slope is just the sign of the number. Absolute value can be piecewisely defined as $y=-x$ for $x\leq 0$ and $y=x$ for $x>0$ the rest comes from the chain rule

Answer (score 2):

First rewrite the absolute value function as a piece-wise defined function  $$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
x-5,  & \text{if $x$ > 5} \\
5-x, & \text{if $x$ $\le$ 5}
\end{cases}$$

Then differentiate

$$f'(x) =
\begin{cases}
1,  & \text{if $x$ > 5} \\
-1, & \text{if $x$ < 5}
\end{cases}$$

Note that the function is not differentiable at $x=5$ . Since $f'(5^+)$ $\neq$ $f'(5^-)$

Answer (score 2):

Rewrite it as $|x - 5| = \sqrt{(x-5)^2}$ then apply the Chain Rule.